# Synchronize a GLSurfaceView with a MapView (Google Map API v2)

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, glsurfaceview

Is it possible to render some OpenGL objects in a GLSurfaceView on top of a MapView and place them with latitude and longitude (synchronize the 2 surfaces).

I would probably need to convert latitude and longitude to screen location but is that possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using a `Renderer` which draws a scene and then creates a bitmap with `glReadPixels`. After that I just had to use the bitmap to add a `GroundOverlay` to my map.